# I want to import after install other packages in pyscript

Tags: python, transform, openai-api, pyscript

I want to install packages like openai or transform.

```
  <py-env>
  - transformer
  - openai
  </py-env>
```

Continue Loading runtime...

Runtime created...

The Initializing components... window appears.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what exactly is your question.

Comment: thank U :) !! Uploaded again. What I want to do is convert an already created python file into pyscript. I don't know how to download packages "pip install"

Comment: Open the browser debugger and post the errors in your question.